# Offset and grouping

Tags: oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I have 2 columns 'a','b'.column a has 20 records and I want to select the first 10 records from column 'a' and update column 'b' for them as 'c'
and then pick the next 10 records from a and update column 'b' for them as 'd'.?
how can I do this?is it possible to use off set in it?
I tried with partition but it is not very helpful,then I thought of offsets but there how do I loop the selection of 10 records a time and update the value ?

```
A B
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

AND I WANT TO TAKE 1ST THREE RECORD OF A AND UPDATE B BY C AND THE NEXT 3 RECORD AND UPDATE B AS D

```
A  B
1  C
2  C
3  C
4  D
5  D
6  D
```

Comment: You need to update your question with some sample data, and the output you're expecting.

Comment: Ok, so in your original logic you had 20 rows, and for the first 10 you wanted your B column values to be C, and for the rest you wanted the value to be D. In your sample data, there are 6 rows, and you want 3 C's and 3 D's. Is the actual requirement "I have X rows, and I want the first half of the rows to have B = C, and the rest to be D"?

Comment: yes exactly...it has be done in a proc

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to handle the case where there are odd rows (do you want more C's or more D's, you could do update the rows using one of the following two merge statements:

More Ds:

```
merge into t1 tgt
using (select a,
              case when rn/cnt <= 0.5 then 'C'
                   else 'D'
              end new_b
       from   (select a,
                      row_number() over (order by a) rn,
                      count(*) over () cnt
               from   t1)) src
on (tgt.a = src.a)
when matched then
update set tgt.b = src.new_b;
```

More Cs:

```
merge into t1 tgt
using (select a,
              case when rn/decode(mod(cnt, 2), 0, cnt, 1, cnt + 1) <= 0.5 then 'C'
                   else 'D'
              end new_b
       from   (select a,
                      row_number() over (order by a) rn,
                      count(*) over () cnt
               from   t1)) src
on (tgt.a = src.a)
when matched then
update set tgt.b = src.new_b;
```

---

See below for the full script I used to test both statements:

```
create table t1 as
select 1 a, cast(null as varchar2(2)) b from dual union all
select 2 a, null b from dual union all
select 3 a, null b from dual union all
select 4 a, null b from dual union all
select 5 a, null b from dual union all
select 6 a, null b from dual;

-- six rows, basic method - for odd rows, there will be a greater number of Ds

merge into t1 tgt
using (select a,
              case when rn/cnt <= 0.5 then 'C'
                   else 'D'
              end new_b
       from   (select a,
                      row_number() over (order by a) rn,
                      count(*) over () cnt
               from   t1)) src
on (tgt.a = src.a)
when matched then
update set tgt.b = src.new_b;

commit;

select * from t1;

         A B 
---------- --
         1 C 
         2 C 
         3 C 
         4 D 
         5 D 
         6 D 

-- six rows, extended method - for odd rows, there will be a greater number of Cs

merge into t1 tgt
using (select a,
              case when rn/decode(mod(cnt, 2), 0, cnt, 1, cnt + 1) <= 0.5 then 'C'
                   else 'D'
              end new_b
       from   (select a,
                      row_number() over (order by a) rn,
                      count(*) over () cnt
               from   t1)) src
on (tgt.a = src.a)
when matched then
update set tgt.b = src.new_b;

commit;

select * from t1;

         A B 
---------- --
         1 C 
         2 C 
         3 C 
         4 D 
         5 D 
         6 D 


insert into t1 (a, b)
values (7, null);

commit;

-- seven rows, basic method - for odd rows, there will be a greater number of Ds

merge into t1 tgt
using (select a,
              case when rn/cnt <= 0.5 then 'C'
                   else 'D'
              end new_b
       from   (select a,
                      row_number() over (order by a) rn,
                      count(*) over () cnt
               from   t1)) src
on (tgt.a = src.a)
when matched then
update set tgt.b = src.new_b;

select * from t1;

         A B 
---------- --
         1 C 
         2 C 
         3 C 
         4 D 
         5 D 
         6 D 
         7 D 

-- seven rows, extended method - for odd rows, there will be a greater number of Cs

merge into t1 tgt
using (select a,
              case when rn/decode(mod(cnt, 2), 0, cnt, 1, cnt + 1) <= 0.5 then 'C'
                   else 'D'
              end new_b
       from   (select a,
                      row_number() over (order by a) rn,
                      count(*) over () cnt
               from   t1)) src
on (tgt.a = src.a)
when matched then
update set tgt.b = src.new_b;

select * from t1;

         A B 
---------- --
         1 C 
         2 C 
         3 C 
         4 C 
         5 D 
         6 D 
         7 D 

drop table t1;
```

Comment: If we don't get into the odd and even number and generate a sequence which suppose gives an output of c,d,e... which further would update the first 3 record of column A with c and then next 3 with d...and so on untill all the records in A have corresponding B..then how do you suggest we go about it?

Comment: what if i do update t1 set b=c where a in (select a from t1 where b is null fetch first 3 rows only) and keep this in loop for updating the rest rows of a ?but this query is not working as it says missing right paranthesis